# add/remove input(text) on keyup of input(number)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been cracking away at this for awhile and cant seem to get it all the way.  I am trying to have it where when a user adds or removes quantity (input type number) that it will add or remove the relevent text inputs.

I know I can do this with a clicking a button or link to remove but I want this to be completely based on the value of the said number input field.

Here is my attempt which adds them correctly but does not remove once I reduce the quantity.

```
var x = 0;

$('.quantity').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.quantity');

    x++;
    var name = "student-name" + x;

    $('<br>').appendTo(parent);
    $("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='Student Name' />")
     .attr("id", name)
     .attr("name", "student-name[]")
    .addClass('student-name')
     .appendTo(parent);
});


$('.quantity').on('keydown', 'input', function() {
    $(this).closest('input.student-name').remove();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/r1zqtftr/3/

Comment: what are you trying to do... are you trying to show as many inputs as the number in the quantity field

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3dc4gfcp/ - handles both delete and addition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyway, you can try this solution :

```
$('.quantity').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
   var parent = $(this).closest('.quantity'); 
   // after all, we delete all the existing created element
   // except first element(1st number field)
   parent.find('input:not(1)').nextAll().remove();
   x++;
   var name = "student-name" + x;


  for(var i = 0; i<$(this).val(); i++)
  {
     $('<br>').appendTo(parent);
     var g =  $("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='Student Name' />")
               .attr({
                 "id": name,
                 "name": "student-name[]"
               })
               .addClass('student-name')
               .appendTo(parent);

 }       
});
```

You can delete the `remove function (keydown)` since we create the input element based on the input number entered.

**UPDATED**

> text inputs that get dynamically generated disappear

This because, we register `keyup` event on all input type, instead of that we need to register only to input text that have the class name with `qty` name like so :

```
// replace old code with this
$('.quantity').on('keyup', 'input.qty', function () { })
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/norlihazmeyGhazali/r1zqtftr/10/)**

Comment: I just noticed there is a bug in this where if you try typing into one of the text inputs that get dynamically generated then all text inputs disappear.  Can you help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AjayMathur/r1zqtftr/5/)

JS:

```
var x = 0;

$('.quantity').on('keyup', 'input', function (e) {

    if (e.which == 8) {
         $(this).parent().find('input.student-name').last().remove().end().parent().find("br").last().remove();
    } else {
        var parent = $(this).closest('.quantity');

        x++;
        var name = "student-name" + x;

        $('<br>').appendTo(parent);
        $("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='Student Name' />")
            .attr("id", name)
            .attr("name", "student-name[]")
            .addClass('student-name')
            .appendTo(parent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Added to remove the br as well Hope its ok.

Comment: Instead of `$(this)` again we can use `end()` and continue in same line. What do you say?

Comment: @joyBlanks I have updated it again, thankx for noticing `br`, appreciate it.

Comment: It works for going up and adding inputs but if I go back it doesnt remove it. In short the quantity field should match the number of available text inputs for pertaining to that quantity field.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
$('.qty').on('change', function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    num = +$this.val() || 0,
    $parent = $this.closest('.quantity'),
    $names = $parent.find('input[name="student-name[]"]');

  if (num < $names.length) {
    $names.slice(num).prev('br').addBack().remove();
  } else {
    for (var i = $names.length; i < num; i++) {
      $('<br>').appendTo($parent);
      $("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='Student Name' />")
        .attr("name", "student-name[]")
        .addClass('student-name')
        .appendTo($parent);
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.amount,
.stock {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="cart">
  <table cellspacing="0" class="group_table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[332]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-332">
            Week 1 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[333]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-333">
            Week 2 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[334]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-334">
            Week 3 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[335]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-335">
            Week 4 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[336]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-336">
            Week 5 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[337]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-337">
            Week 6 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="quantity">
            <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Qty" value="0" name="quantity[338]" max="70" min="0" step="1" />
          </div>
        </td>

        <td class="label">
          <label for="product-338">
            Week 7 &ndash; Summer Workshop</label>
        </td>


        <td class="price">
          <span class="amount">$325.00</span>
          <p class="stock in-stock">In stock</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <input type="hidden" value="362" name="add-to-cart" />


  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="wc-deposits-options-form">
    <hr class="separator" />
    <label class="deposit-option">
      Deposit Option: <span id="deposit-amount"><span class="amount">$162.50</span></span>
      <span id="deposit-suffix">per item</span>
    </label>
    <div class="deposit-options switch-toggle switch-candy switch-woocommerce-deposits">
      <input type="radio" value="deposit" class="input-radio" checked="checked" name="deposit-radio" id="pay-deposit" />
      <label onclick="" for="pay-deposit"><span>Pay Deposit</span>
      </label>
      <input type="radio" disabled="" class="input-radio" name="deposit-radio" id="pay-full-amount" />
      <label onclick="" for="pay-full-amount"><span>Full Amount</span>
      </label>
      <a class="wc-deposits-switcher"></a>
    </div>
    <span id="wc-deposits-notice" class="deposit-message"></span>
  </div>

  <button class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt" type="submit">PAY DEPOSIT NOW</button>


</form>

<!--
<div id="myDiv">
    <input type="number" id="qty1" value="1" />
    <input type="text" id="txt_1" />
</div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/tL3oqqyy/

Code:

```
var x = 0;

function getUid() {
    return ++x;
}

function getStudentId() {
    return "student-name" + getUid();
}

$('.quantity').on('keyup', 'input', function() {

    var parent = $(this).closest('.quantity'); 
    var numberValue = parseInt($(this).val());

    parent.find('input:not(1)').nextAll().remove();

    for ( i=0; i < numberValue; i++)
    {
        $(parent).append('<br />');
        $(parent).append(
            $("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='Student Name' />")
            .attr("id", getStudentId())
            .attr("name", "student-name[]")
            .addClass('student-name')
        ); 
    }    

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try utilizing `change` event , removing `input` , preceding `br` elements , comparing `.length` of `input[type=text]` elements within `.quantity` to value of `input[type=number]` element , `this` within `change` event handler

var x = 0;

$('.quantity').on('change', 'input', function () {
    var parent = $(this).closest('.quantity');

```
x++;
var name = "student-name" + x;

$('<br>').appendTo(parent);

var n = this.value;
if ($("input[type=text]", parent).length < n) {
$("<input type='text' value='' placeholder='Student Name' />")
    .attr("id", name)
    .attr("name", "student-name[]")
    .addClass('student-name')
    .before("<br>")
    .appendTo(parent);
}
  else {
  $("input[type=text]", parent).each(function(i, el) {
    if (i >= n) $(el).remove(); $("br", parent).eq(i).remove()
  })
}
```

});

https://jsfiddle.net/r1zqtftr/9/